# Polymer element without the shadow dom's styling encapsulation

Tags: css, polymer, shadow-dom

I've written a few Polymer components so far and for my more complicated stuff I love how their styling is isolated from the rest of the page. It's been much easier to use them across multiple apps.

However, today I'm creating a super simple component, and I'm realizing that I'd really like to have the page's styles bleed in. I've got a component that packages up a bunch of logic, but just renders a basic `<a href>` link. Is it possible through CSS or other means to have that link inherit its styling from the rest of the page?

Comment: Final note for those that come after. This element was simple enough that I ended up not using templating or the shadow dom at all. In my element's ready callback I just do some ordinary dom manipulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appyAuthorStyles` used to be great for this. Unfortunately, it's no longer in the Shadow DOM spec.

Your two solutions are:

1. Create a small stylesheet (e.g. shared.css) that includes the common rules the page and component use.
2. Use [`::shadow` and `/deep/`](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html#style-fromoutside) to style the link from the outside, the same way as the page styles its links.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer on this! I'd just come to the same conclusion. Some links for others who come along after. Here's some discussion for why applyAuthorStyles was removed: https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=23625 and if you see reference to the cat and hat selectors (^^ and ^) those have since been renamed /deep/ and ::shadow respectively.

Comment: One note, it looks like there was at least at one time a lightdom attribute that would cause the polymer template to be rendered into the light dom, though I can't seem to get it to work myself: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/222 and https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/commit/d8d0a4d